# Eclipse Juno don't remember workspace address

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I changed workspace address to cd E. But when I open Eclipse, it open workspace address default in cd C and I must chose File -> Switch Workspace -> E:...; then Eclipse restart and open my workspace in cd E. I don' know how fix that. :(

Comment: I'm having similar issue with one of my Eclipse installations, and I think the culprit is Google Plugin for Eclipse. Try some fresh installation and check if you have same issue there.

Comment: Yes. I having Google Plugin: Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

It should save the workspace, so I'm not really sure why that's happening to you. Maybe try re-installing eclipse. When you re-install during the setup there should be a place that allows you to set the default workspace. If that still doesn't work try netbeans. It's essentially the same thing, and it may save you some pain if you don't feel like dealing with the problem.

Comment: I don't want re-installing because I add some plugin. :(

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest trying Eclipse Kepler (4.3). I've tried installing GAE plugin into it and the problem does not seem to exist anymore.

I understand that you don't really want to re-install everything you set up for the current installation, but Juno is said to be very buggy by itself. And in Kepler a lot of Juno issues are fixed, so it worth updating anyways. Also Kepler SR1 (4.3.1) is planned for September 27th, so it may worth waiting a week.

Also, note that for Kepler the Google Plugin update site url is [dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3) (it was [dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2) for Juno).